# c# link two dynamically added controls. (Windows form application)

Tags: c#, dynamic, combobox

This i a pretty basic question, but i can't find the solution anywere.

I have this code, that dynamically creates a combobox and a label when the user presses a button. My qustion is now, how can I link the combobox and the label so that the label shows what is selected in the combobox?

```
// Tilføjer combobox
ComboBox cboRun = new ComboBox();
cboRun.Name = "cboDynamic1" + c++;
cboRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10 + (20 * c));
cboRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 25);
cboRun.BringToFront();
cboRun.Enter += CBox_Enter;
grb_MealOne.Controls.Add(cboRun);

// Tilføjer label
Label labRun = new Label();
labRun.Name = "labDynamic1" + c;
labRun.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(270, 10 + (20 * c));
labRun.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
labRun.BringToFront();
labRun.Text = "Neee";
grb_MealOne.Controls.Add(labRun);
```

i really dont have any idea on how to do this part. Have tried many different things!

Comment: You must save these control in a array or sth else (like list)

Answer (score 0):

```
Label L;
public void YourMethod()
{
    //Create the `ComboBox1` and set the event `comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged` to it
    Label Y = new Label();
    // ...
    L = Y;
}
public void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    L.Text = "Something else";
}
```

this field (`L`) is your `Label` and you can use it anywhere.

Comment: But doesn't this only work when the name of the combobox is 'combobox1'?

Thanks!

Comment: No!! Just name the `ComboBox` whatever you want! The point is, you should store the label in a field of the class, and then change the  text in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event of your `ComboBox`! That's it! So easy!

Comment: @janusMack Please do your homework before asking questions on StackOverflow. And what is your homework? Here it is: Reading books about your programming language and your environment, Reading the documentation of your programming language and your library (C# and .NET here), reading lots of code samples, trying different ways, and finally searching the web.